# Как правильно верстать под iPhone?

Tags: html, css

Есть верстка.
Сверстано и под мобильники:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
```

А под новые iPhone как правильно верстать? Протестировать нет возможности.

Comment: Можешь попробовать Bootstrap Grid system чтобы верстать правильно для iphone. а как протестировать я не знаю.

Comment: На [**Screenfly**](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) можно посмотреть, как выглядит страница на iPhone 3,4,5,6,7, 6/7 Plus, iPad и iPad Pro. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

- [Узнать поддерживается ли свойство в браузере](https://caniuse.com/)
- [Посмотреть как будет выглядеть](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/how-to-use-google-chrome-device-emulation-feature.html)

Всё просто)

Хотя можно воспользоваться платными эмуляторами...